How to update value using Callbacks in FLutter for the given scenario?
I have a stateless Widget A and stateful widget B. A calls B (B is one of the children of A). A has a function inside widget D (D is also child of A) which needs C bool value to compare, which is set in B widget's function. How do I propagate C from B to A?
Also, I want C to be optional, so that every time A is rendered it's value become null.

Either simplify your widget structure or use an external view model.

Try this:

comment/uncomment class A (switch between stateless or stateful)

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class B extends StatefulWidget {
   //define a callback and call it when c is updated
  final ValueChanged<bool?> onChanged;
  const B({super.key, required this.onChanged});

  @override
  State<B> createState() => _BState();
}

class _BState extends State<B> {
  bool? c;
  void updateC(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      c = value;
    });
    widget.onChanged(c);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            updateC(true); //update c to true
          },
          child: const Text('Update C')),
    );
  }
}


class A extends StatefulWidget {
  const A({super.key});

  @override
  State<A> createState() => _AState();
}

class _AState extends State<A> {
  bool? c;

  void handleCChanged(bool? value) {
    // c = value; //update the c value not visible on screen

    //need to use setState for showing the updated value on screen
    setState(() {
      c = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          B(onChanged: handleCChanged),
          D(c: c),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


/*
class A extends StatelessWidget {
  bool? c; //c will be updated by callback
  A({super.key, this.c});

  void handleCChanged(bool? value) {
    c = value; //update the c value
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          B(onChanged: handleCChanged),
          D(c: c),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
 */
class D extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool? c;
  const D({super.key, this.c});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Using the value of C for comparison or any other logic
    return Text('Value of C: ${c.toString()}');
  }
}


